# Condtionnal text coloring in table

Tags: angular

I have an array of User object. Each user has a subscription end date. I'm displaying everything in a table, but I'd like to have the date column in red if it's in the past. What would be the best implementation for that ?

```html
<tr>
    <td>{{user.id}} - {{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.subStartDate| date: 'YYYY-MM-dd'}}</td>
    <td>{{user.subEndDate| date: 'YYYY-MM-dd'}}</td>  <--- if this is in the past, goes RED
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a [class.] attribute on the item that you want to color (tr for the whole row or the single td for the cell) and apply a custom class to the item to set it's background.

Es.

```
<tr>
     <td>{{user.id}} - {{user.name}}</td>
     <td>{{user.subStartDate| date: 'YYYY-MM-dd'}}</td>
     <td [class.expired-item-date]="isPastDate(user.subEndDate)">{{user.subEndDate| date: 'YYYY-MM-dd'}}</td>
</tr>
```

The in the controller create the isPastDate method like this

```
public isPastDate(date: Date) {
    const now = new Date();
    return date < now;
}
```

Then in the css of the component you can customize the class as you like, to color the background you can use something like

```
.expired-item-date {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks it works :), I didn't know you could make a conditionnal class. I'll validate this in 5 mins